# How to effectively search Internet for graphs not for function graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question

So, is there any way to distinguish graphs and plots in Internet?

I was looking for (Olivier-)Ricci curvature of graphs and found a lot about Ricci curvature of function graphs and not so much about my topic.

P.S. This question is expected to be really old enough, but I couldn't find any link, since this problem again involves Internet search. I suppose that community will offer some tricks to add in something like Wikipedia article on Graph Theory in order to help future generations of mathematicians.

Comment: For your particular inquiry, I think using the keyword "discrete Ricci curvature" helps to get stuff related only to graphs.

Comment: @SamHopkins, I already tried to google it in Russian, got some ideas and then googled "curvature of hypergraphs". It worked nicely. However, not everyone is familiar with Russian language.

Answer (score 10):

Use Google Scholar instead of plain Google; I simply entered [graphs](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=graphs&btnG=) and pretty much all the items returned by Google Scholar refer to graphs in the mathematical context.

It also suggests helpful specialized search terms:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Search using "edge", "vertex", and/or "node" as keywords instead of "graph".

Comment: I suggest *as well as*, rather than *instead of*. The word *edge*, in particular, is very common.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit "vertex" in as well.